# Why am I getting an authentification ERROR message after "knife cookbook list" in the chef "upload a cookbook tutorial?"

Tags: linux, terminal, chef-infra, virtual-machine

I'm going through chef server training under:

Learn Chef>Tutorials>Manage a node>Red Hat Enterprise Linux>Hosted Chef>Upload a cookbook to Chef server

The tutorial has just had me use 
`"knife cookbook upload learn_chef_httpd"` in the terminal but when I `"knife cookbook list"` instead of verifying like the tutorial shows, it returns:

```
ERROR: Failed to authenticate to https://api.chef.io/organizations/utopiartstudios as wolf4091 with key /Users/gavindevops/learn-chef/.chef/utopiartstudios-validator.pem
Response:  Invalid signature for user or client 'wolf4091'
```

I tried nano'ing into the knife.rb file to adjust the client key as it was originally the wrong file name, but it still won't work. I am at a loss. Sorry if this is noobie stuff.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear for me, did you managed to upload cookbook without any issues? And `knife cookbook list` just fails? You shouldn't authenticate with organization validator key, you should use your private key.

Comment: yeah what happened was I downloaded the wrong .pem from the chef manager. Duuhh. My bad everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've mixed the user key and the validator key. In your `.chef/knife.rb` (or `.chef/config.rb`, same thing), you have a line like `client_key`. That should be pointing at your user key, probably something like `/Users/gavindevops/learn-chef/.chef/wolf4091.pem` or similar. So all together:

```
client_key '/Users/gavindevops/learn-chef/.chef/wolf4091.pem'
```

If you've got more questions, I recommend jumping on our [community Slack team](http://community-slack.chef.io/) for more real-time help.

Comment: you're right. I downloaded the organization .pem key instead of the user .pem key. Oh lord... Well thank you much coderanger! Angel Grove is in your debt.